# How to recover a dog from maggots?

Tags: dogs, medicines, aggression, diseases, infections

My pet is a Labrador breed and he is suffering from maggots. He is too aggressive and does not let any of my family members touch his wound. He has maggots in his right leg at his palm and it's increasing day by day. I have tried using the spray to cure it but he won't let me apply the spray on his wound. What can I do so that I can apply the medicines?

Comment: Maggots eat dead tissue.  So, you are beyond a simple spray or medicine, and unless you know how to mechanically “[dibris](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debridement)” a wound, it's over your head. The maggots may even prevent sepsis from setting in.

Answer (score 5):

He needs to go to a veterinarian to assess the damage, you will need a prescription antiparasitic as well as antibiotics and pain meds.

They will be able to handle an aggressive dog.

Comment: "Take him to the vet" is a cop out. Anybody can say that. That is not useful advice. The guy already knows he can take the dog to a vet. If he wanted to take the dog to the vet, he wouldn't be asking about it here would he?

Comment: Nobody on here can give good advice on this situation because they are not physically able to see the dog. Nobody here knows how deep this maggots are in the dog, it's dangerous to give out advice on this without him seeing a veterinarian.

Comment: it's not a cop-out it's called being ethical.

Comment: I have consulted a vet and his treatment is going on. Thanks for your valuable replies. It was a great help to me.

Comment: @Mrunmesh you're very welcome, glad you got him help :)